# What does '^' mean?

Tags: python, syntax, symbols

I ran the code:

`a = 1^2`

`b = 3^2`

`c = 1^3`

`d = 5^9`

`print(a)`

`print(b)`

`print(c)`

`print(d)`

**Output:**

*3*

*1*

*2*

*12*

***But what does ^ actually do?***

Comment: It's a bitwise "OR" operator. You can read more on: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-bitwise-operators/

Comment: @SeraphWedd: No, it's bitwise XOR. (`|` is for OR.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, forgot to press X I guess. :D

Comment: Check out this link https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html